# Экспорт компонентов vue для переиспользования

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

Я реализовал api. И к нему отдельно используя vuecli создал одностраничный интерфейс. В планах встраивать его в нужных мне проектах. Вопрос заключается в том,  что нужно сделать, чтобы экспортировать написанное приложение и переиспользовать его, где необходимо?

Структура проекта представлена на скриншоте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- `src/main.js` - подключаю и настраиваю axios
- `src/App.vue` - описываю основной компонент приложения (возможно, нужно вынести его в отдельный компонент в папку components)
- `src/components/OneDay.vue` - второй компонент, который вызывается в основном `src/App.vue` несколько раз.
- `src/mixins/dateHandler.js` - несколько общих для двух компонентов функций, которые подключая в виде mixins.

Никакие другие файлы я не модифицировал. Как мне правильно это подготовить, чтобы можно было подключать эти компоненты к другим своим приложениям, используя composer? Подключаю, настраиваю некоторые переменные (адрес api, например) и вывожу в нужном страницы - так я это вижу.